# ServerConnection doesn't work with a connection string

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I use below code to create backup from my database in c#.net. but when I run Code I getting this error :

> Failed to connect to server Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AngularJs;Integrated Security=True.

my code to do this is :

```
ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection("Data Source=" + txtServerName.Text + ";Initial Catalog=" + drpDatabases.SelectedItem.ToString() + ";Integrated Security=True");
        Server server = new Server(con);
        Backup source = new Backup();
        source.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
        source.Database = drpDatabases.SelectedItem.ToString();
        BackupDeviceItem destination = new BackupDeviceItem(Path, DeviceType.File);
        source.Devices.Add(destination);
        source.SqlBackup(server);
        con.Disconnect();
```

Where is Problem ? Why this is not work ?
I tested connections string with  sqlconnection its work fine and open very well .

Comment: My guess is that txtServerName.Text is populated with a "." and is looking for a server name.

Comment: yes text server = . ; is it wrong?

Comment: I usually see Data Source=ServerName

Comment: I use . becuse database is local

Comment: tested by (local) but getting that error

Comment: what Database Engine are you using?

Comment: @JCBorlagdan SQL server 2014 and 2008

Answer (score 1):

The [ServerConnection(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191560.aspx) overload expects an instance name, not a connection string. You can simply write `new ServerConnection(".")` or :

```
var con = new ServerConnection(txtServerName.Text);
```

The error message tells you that `ServerConnection` tried to connect to a server having a name the same as the *entire* connection string and failed.

A ServerConnection represents a connection to a specific *server*, not a database, so it doesn't need a SqlConnection object. If you supply one, it's used only to extract the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ServerConnection con= new ServerConnection(new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cnstring).DataSource);
```

Comment: If I'm right, SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cnstring).DataSource will only return server name, not all items of connection string like user/password !

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong, use:

```
ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection(
   new SqlConnection(
       "Data Source=" + txtServerName.Text + ";Initial Catalog=" 
       + drpDatabases.SelectedItem.ToString() 
       + ";Integrated Security=True"));
```

Comment: You should explain that [ServerConnection(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191560.aspx) expects an instance name, not a connection string. The OP could also write `new ServerConnection(txtServerName.Text)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + txtServerName.Text + ";Initial Catalog=" + drpDatabases.SelectedItem.ToString() + ";Integrated Security=True");
SeverConnection scon = new ServerConnection(con);
Server svr = new Server(scon);
```

because I think you're passing an incorrect parameter for the ServerConnection.